# Reference of copied object is changed when using copied object to assign to global variable

Tags: python, numpy

I have a global variable that contains a numpy array for an image, in my function I first create a copy of that image using copy.copy(img) and then in the infinite loop I try to reassign the copied image to the global variable whenever a certain key is pressed, this is kind of the structure of the relevant code:

```
img = np array 
def label_image():
    global img
    img_copy = copy.copy(img)
    while(1):
        imshow(img)
        if spacebar is pressed:
            img = img_copy
```

Now when I press space once, img takes the values of img_copy, but as a side effect img_copy is now assigned the reference to img, so that `id(img_copy) == id(img)` after the assignment `img = img_copy`.

Can anybody tell me why this happens and how to keep the original values of img_copy and still assign the content of img_copy to img?

Comment: I make this recommendation to all newish python programmers: forget `global` exists because it is almost always the wrong thing especially with instance, class, and module scoped identifiers. I'd be tempted to add `copy.copy()` to that list as I almost never (as in can't remember the last time) I used it.

Comment: I have read that as well, however my problem here is that I'm using OpenCV's event handling and I can't pass the image that is to be marked as an argument to the callback function, so global variables were the only option I could think of. If you have a better alternative for such a problem, I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: You can probably pass a module scoped variable to the callback registration. A module is just a variable assigned at the top level of you `mycode.py` file; which can be accessed as `mycode.variable` outside the module or referred to as `variable` inside the mycode module. Thus you can call `opencv.subpackage.register_callback(some_function, variable)` and it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy the values in `img_copy` into the array `img`:

```
img[...] = img_copy
```

(The ellipsis is literal, not something that I left for you to fill in.)

---

*"Now when I press space once, img takes the values of img_copy, but as a side effect img_copy is now assigned the reference to img, so that id(img_copy) == id(img) after the assignment img = img_copy.*

*Can anybody tell me why this happens..."*

Because that is how assignment with `=` works in python!  When you say `a = b`, `a` and `b` are now just different names of the same object; no copying takes place.

---

One more note: instead of using the `copy` module in this line:

```
    img_copy = copy.copy(img)
```

you can use the numpy array's [`copy()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.copy.html) method:

```
    img_copy = img.copy()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is true that you end up with the same id for both names, but the reason is that you have assigned `img_copy` to image, not the other way around.  Once you make this assignment, you have two names for the same (new copy!) object.  Here's a way to see this.

```
img = np.arange(12).reshape((3,4))
def label_image():
    global img
    print id(img)               #see original id
    img_copy = copy.copy(img)   #make a new copy
    if True:
        img = img_copy          #assigns new copy to img
    print(id(img),id(img_copy)) #verify that both reference new copy
```

In this context, it is unclear what else you wish to happen.